# Explanation of 'nineteenth century' and 'nineties'

Tags: grammar, etymology

Please help find what is the logic behind:

1. Nineteenth century
2. Nineties (decade)

By googling I found that (1) means 1801-1900 so we call it "nineteenth century." It is being called by the last of the years (i.e., 1900). But (2) is 90–99 and is being called by the first of the range (i.e., 90). Please help me out since I find it confusing in many cases.

Comment: It all depends on your point of reference.  Up until the year 2000, the years 1890-1899 were referred to as "the nineties" or, when speaking of the culture of the era, "the Gay Nineties".  Now, of course, when you speak of "the nineties" you must somehow, explicitly or via context, identify what century you're referring to.  But the 1990s were not that gay (in fact, the term was deprecated by that point), so "the Gay Nineties" will always refer to the 1890s.

Comment: With regard to the "Nineteenth Century", that refers to the years 1800-1899 -- the "First Century" is considered to have started with the year 0000 AD (which of course never existed, but calendars have never been all that logical).

Comment: @HotLicks: I'd want to see a citation for that.

Comment: Here is a sort of reference for the "naughty nineties" (1890s, that is): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVzSvNE90mI

Comment: I'm voting to close this question off topic because it's not about the English language. It's about western civilization.

Comment: @tchrist should I delete the post? even a top scorer edited the question several others voted the answer. Then my question why this has not been nipped in the bud?

Answer (score 2):

In some ways this is all about random convention, but in the spirit of making this be about English grammar, notice that ***nineteenth* is an [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics))** while *nineties* is not.

That is, having a nineteenth century presupposes an eighteenth, seventeenth, etcetera, on back to the first century. The [first century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_century) of the common era is defined as the years 1-99 (or 100 for the extreme pedants among us). The reason for this is probably best left as a question for History SE.

The criterion for the term "nineties" is different: it only has to have "ninety" in the number. Nowadays, this usually refers to the decade 1990-1999, but the term "[gay nineties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_Nineties)" used to be quite common, referring to social and cultural events of the years 1890-1899.

Although we now use "nineties" to refer to a decade in some century or another, it wouldn't surprise me(*) if some 11th-millennium wag would refer to the years 9000-9999 nostalgically as the "nineties".

Comment: (*)Admittedly, I will be beyond surprise (if you insist, actually "dead") at that point.

Comment: @tchrist The 18th Century is already a lie, because 1752 is missing 11 days?

Comment: Looks like I forgot that this SE is the Fount Of All Pedantry. Next Winter Bash, EL&U should award Extreme Pedant hats.

Comment: So long as you believe that ninety-nine years is the same as a hundred years, I assume you won’t mind sending me a buck for every hundred you earn.  After all, you'll still have a hundred by your count.

Comment: +hat for @tchrist. :) Anyway, it's simple recognition of a muddled situation. The first century is anchored in nothing but a sixth-century monk's inaccurate calculations. Also, astronomers use "Year zero" to refer to 1BCE. No more arguing about this; it's out of scope.

Comment: It's the same logic as the old custom, sometimes seen on tombstones, of stating someone's age as 'in his fortieth year', i.e. he was 39. You complete your 40th year on your 40th birthday.

Comment: As for the question of why there is no year zero, the concept of zero was not invented until the seventh century C.E.

Comment: @spencer I know what you meant but the problem arises when I am to chose an option from multiple choice question in the exam of whicg questions are selected by a facy wag

Comment: @Sislam I think I answered your question, but unfortunately I also tried to be clever about a peripheral issue and the fancy wags fixated on that.